# PHP, как получить изображение из ресурса?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

У меня есть код, который возвращает ресурс изображения видом `imagepng($this->image)`.

Мне нужно каким-то образом сделать из изображения путь к изображению, базируясь на этом мануале: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

В общем, мне нужно обработать ресурс и отправить фото в Телеграм, но я никак не пойму как и что делать с этим ресурсом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохрани изображение в файл передав имя файла вторым параметром в imagepng, и отправь файл через curl по Telegram Bot API:

```
$tmpfilename = tempnam("/tmp", "img");
imagepng($this->image, $tmpfilename);

$bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_id>/";
$url        = $bot_url . "sendPhoto?chat_id=" . $chat_id ;

$post_fields = array(
    'chat_id'   => $chat_id,
    'photo'     => new CURLFile($tmpfilename)
);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

unlink($tmpfilename);
```